# Bootstrap Datetimepicket: Table td Width Size Does not get Resized

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, datetimepicker

I am using Bootstrap `Datetimepicket` and I am trying to resize the width of its table `td` so I compensate of the padding; however, no matter what styles I apply on it, there is no effect. What I am trying to do is resize the `td` so it is not as wide. The image below shows the width that of `td`, which contain dates numbers and their width size, which I am trying to change:

[image]

I have this currently applied to the td class:

```
td.day {
        height: 15px !important;
        line-height: 12px !important;
        width: 15px !important;
        border-radius: 7px !important;
    }
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated!

Comment: have you tried inspecting the code in devtools? you can turn on and off as well as write code to live test. Probably flex positioned elements

Comment: I have turned off everything and removed classes as well. No effect! It is frustrating really